# Java Mac OS X running with out a Dock Icon

Tags: java, macos, swing

i have a swing application that i would like to run on os x without a dock icon. Just a system tray icon. I know about headless but if i set that property i can not create JFrames.

Is it possible to run a swing application without a dock icon in java? or through JNA if there is a native way.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: packaging it as .app (which is pretty standard for a Java app on OS X) and then doing what Matt Wilson suggested fixed the issue.  So, *"yes. Next useful (or is it) comment?"*  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to package it up as a .app (Mac application package), and in the package's Info.plist set LSUIElement to 1. See http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?LSUIElement.